# Fontspec / Polyglossia error after windows 10 update

Tags: miktex, fontspec, windows, polyglossia

I have recently (about a week) updated the operating system from windows 7 to windows 10. As for this moment, any use of the `fontspec` or `polyglossia` packages won't compile.

After the problem occurred, I have updated Miktex using both the admin and non-admin options. I have also tried "refresh FDNB" and "update formats" in the Miktex "Setting" tool (both admin and non-admin). However, the problem was not solved.

I have uninstalled and installed Miktex 2.9 again. After installation I have updated Miktex (both admin and non-admin) and applied "Refresh FDNB" and "Update Format" in the Miktex "Setting" tool. Yet, the compilation error continues.

An example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}

\begin{document}
    This is a new document!
\end{document}
```

When compiling the above code using XeLaTeX (Miktex 2.9 and TexStudio) I get the following massages: [linked file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/23uro25tdk1fphj/Massages.txt?dl=0).The log file is linked [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b2cihy5fye5gkyo/document.txt?dl=0).

Any help in this matter would be very appreciated.

Comment: Show the complete log of your example (exactly this example!)

Comment: @Ulrike Fische Thanks for your reply. I have reedited the question and included links to both the log file and the messages given by the editor.

Comment: Your system is not up-to-date. The files in `"C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\ `  are new and ok, but the files in `C:\Users\Avraham\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9` are too old. Run in your user account the update manager (not the update manager (admin)).

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer. Thanks again. I ran the update manager as you suggested, then ran the "Refresh FDNB" and "Update Formats" in "Miktex Settings". The problem remains.

Comment: Did the update manager show any updates?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Yes. It showed the "babel-french" and "polyglossia" packages. Strangely, they appear again if I run the update again, as they were not installed. Here is a
[screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/225oormfp7ujr1b/Screenshot_1.png?dl=0). These packages do not show up when I run the update manager (admin).
The new [log file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tajpphc3zux1whh/log_2.txt?dl=0) (seems the same).
Might there be some problem with the updating process?

Comment: There is certainly something wrong, if it shows an update from last year. It is difficult to debug such problems when you don't have access to the PC. You could try to switch to another repository (in the package manager (non admin and admin). You can also try to deinstall and reinstall in the package manager the l3kernel- package.